# How to dispose subscription?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I dispose subscription if my class is not in StatefulWidge? Is there any method?

```js
class EventNotifier extends ValueNotifier<List<String>> {
  EventNotifier(List<String> value) : super(value);
  final List<String> events = ['add', 'delete', 'edit'];
  final stream = Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  late final streamSub = stream.listen(
    (event) {
      value.add(
        events[Random().nextInt(3)],
      );
      notifyListeners();
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's necessary in this case, since both the stream and subscription will be freed by the GC when the instance is freed.

However, `ValueNotifier` does have a [dispose method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/dispose.html). You can override it, and cancel your stream from there if you need to:

```dart
class EventNotifier extends ValueNotifier<List<String>> {
  // Omitted

  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamSub.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```